# How to get the name of a segment by using its `Elf64_Phdr` program header?

Tags: linux, elf

As I know, a ELF object consists of a number of segments, each of which has a corresponding program header describing the segment. In `libelf`, a program header is defined as a `Elf64_Phdr` (or `Elf32_Phdr`) structure, and a `Elf64_Phdr` structure is defined like this:

```
typedef struct {
    Elf32_Word  p_type;    /* Segment type */
    Elf32_Off   p_offset;  /* Segment file offset */
    Elf32_Addr  p_vaddr;   /* Segment virtual address */
    Elf32_Addr  p_paddr;   /* Segment physical address */
    Elf32_Word  p_filesz;  /* Segment size in file */
    Elf32_Word  p_memsz;   /* Segment size in memory */
    Elf32_Word  p_flags;   /* Segment flags */
    Elf32_Word  p_align;   /* Segment alignment */
} Elf32_Phdr;
```

However, segments have names (don't they?) and `Elf64_Phdr` structures don't have a field which points to their corresponding names. So, how to get a name of a segment of an ELF file from its corresponding program header? Or is the `p_type` field enough to identify a segment, so that segments don't have names?

Comment: "However, segments have names" => ELF has section names, but no segment names. Other binary formats do things differently, however: Mach-O has names for both segments and sections. PE-COFF has named sections, but no segments (albeit one occasionally finds PE-COFF sections called "segments", even if that isn't technically correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, segments have names (don't they?)

No, they don't.

> Or is the p_type field enough to identify a segment, so that segments don't have names?

Correct.